# Strange IllegalArguementException in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to open a gallery of images with an item on a nav drawer but I'm getting this error:

```
04-17 13:21:19.067: E/FragmentManager(9210): No view found for id 0x7f0c005e (com.example.example:id/content_frame) for fragment ImageGallery {42721da8 #0 id=0x7f0c005e}
04-17 13:21:19.067: E/FragmentManager(9210): Activity state:
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210): Process: com.example.example, PID: 9210
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c005e (com.example.example:id/content_frame) for fragment ImageGallery{42721da8 #0 id=0x7f0c005e}
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-17 13:21:19.087: E/AndroidRuntime(9210):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is where I call the ImageGallery to be opened:

```
//Handle what happens when each nav drawer item is pressed
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment newFragment = new FragmentHome();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                newFragment = new ImageGallery();
                break;
        }

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment).commit();

        mLeftDrawer.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mFragmentTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);
}
```

Let me know if I should post the image gallery code as well. Note it's very long so that's why it's not here.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

Here is the layout for the gallery:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the drawer layout with content_frame in it as well:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layouts that contain the content_frame. The stack trace says that it cannot find this.

Comment: Exactly, it suggest you that content_frame view is not within your content layout.

Comment: You can try to clean project to generate ids again. Ids can generated incorrectly if you change resources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the layout that you specified in your setContentView() in the onCreate() method.

The layout that you are trying to use in the:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment).commit();
```

must be a child of that layout. Without the onCreate() method it is difficult to diagnose your issue but this is where I would start.